# Javascript break breaks Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox

I'm working on this Javascript script that works nice in Safari and Chome but for some reason it doesn't work at all in Firefox. I identified the line that caused this: it's "break;".

How do I fix this?

Comment: can't you post the code?

Comment: Post the code on jsbin http://jsbin.com/ so we can run it

Comment: I just did: http://jsbin.com/upune3/3/edit

It's only a part of Jplayer's code though.

Comment: Why use break if you do not want to break Firefox ?!
  Just joking :)

Comment: What is the reason for the break? You're not in a loop, and no other code would run....wouldn't just removing that line solve the problem?

Comment: Because for some reason the onclick event will go more than once when I click only once. I haven't figured out why yet, but since it worked this way I just kept it.

Comment: @Maxime - That shouldn't be the case, you're getting a handler bound multiple times...are you running any of this code in a loop, or inside another event in the real page?

Comment: Yes, actually the function playlistchange can be triggered a few times in the page. I can't think of a best way to do this though. This code really needs to be parsed exactly when a change in the playlist occurs.

Comment: @Maxime - In that case, call `.unbind('click').click(...` and remove the `break;`, do you have any issues then?

Comment: Ok, I got it. Well the script doesn't work 100% like it's supposed to, but at least it works the same for Safari and Firefox. I'll try rewriting it tomorrow and find a solution with unbind(). Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

What Nick said (remove the break)! If you are attempting to stop the event from bubbling try:

```
e.stopPropagation(); // this will stop any other parent handlers from firing
e.stopImmediatePropagation(); // this will stop any other handlers (including on the current object from firing.
e.preventDefault(); // this will stop the browser from handling the event.
```